# My script crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, settimeout

My script runs but when it gets to the setTimeout part it just doesn't like it :(
The browser crashes and I have to exit. Is the browser wrong or have I dun goofed?

```
var health=100;
var ehealth=100;
var atk;
var eatk;

function attack(x){
x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
atk=x;
ehealth=ehealth-atk
document.write('Enemy Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + ehealth + '&nbsp; &nbsp;')
}

function eattack(x){
x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
eatk=x;
health=health-eatk
document.write('Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + health )
}

function dead(){
if(health<=0){
    document.write('You Lose');
}else{
    if(ehealth<=0){
  document.write('You Win');
}
}
}

function battle(){
document.write('Enemy Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + ehealth + '&nbsp; &nbsp; Health: &nbsp; &nbsp;' + health + '<br/>\n')
while(health>=0&&ehealth>=0){
setTimeout(function(){
    attack(0)
},400)
setTimeout(function(){
eattack(0)
},400)
document.write("<br/>\n");
dead();
}
}
```

What am I to do :(

Comment: Not sure why it's crashing, but please, do **not** use document.write like that. Either use ``console.log``, or modify the text-value of a specific element you have designated for it.

Comment: Your `while` loop doesn't terminate. You trigger an endless stream of `setTimeout()` callbacks, but due to JS being executed in just one thread, none of these callbacks gets executed ever.

Comment: while(health>=0&&ehealth>=0) thats like forever?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes it is, if you do not change the variables anywhere in that loop.

Comment: If you want to do timings I'd suggest you look at Promises/Deferreds.

Comment: @Sirko yes I was aware just getting the OP attention :)

Comment: What's an OP? Also I thought that my attack script lowered the value of ehealth and vice-versa for the eattack script, such that the setTimeout would terminate

Comment: As you're calling both functions on 400ms intervals why not have a single timer, run both attacks, test dead and if neither side has died set another timeout at that stage.  As it stands you are setting up thousands of timeouts because the while loop will not terminate until at least 400ms has elapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop doesn't terminate. You trigger an endless stream of setTimeout() callbacks, but due to JS being executed in just one thread, none of these callbacks gets executed ever.

Let's see what happens in more detail:

in the event loop (the queue for JS code to be executed) at first there is just you battle function.

After the first iteration of the while loop, the event loop still looks like this:

```
battle | attack | eattack
```

The functions using `setTimeout()` get queued behind your `battle()` function. After the next iteration, it looks like this

```
battle | attack | eattack | attack | eattack
```

But still no `(e)attack()` function has been executed and hence the `health` and `ehealth` variables remain unchanged. This goes on and on forever until your browser has eaten all the memory and breaks down.

As a solution I suggest introducing something like this:

```
function battleRound() {
  attack(0);
  eattack(0);

  dead();

  if( health>=0&&ehealth>=0 ) {
    // still a round to go
    setTimeout( battleRound, 400 );
  }
}
```

Instead of queuing a multitude of functions, just enqueue one round of fighting after another until the battle is over.

Comment: This actually makes sense to me :) Thank you and I hope it works!

Comment: It......worked you incredible star I would upvote except I have 1 rep :( Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your while loop:

```
while(health>=0&&ehealth>=0){
setTimeout(function(){
    attack(0)
},400)
```

your are setting attack function to execute an "infinite" number of time.

Comment: How would I fix that because I thought that, since I was lowering the values of health and ehealth it would eventually terminate

Answer (score 0):

Generally your code tries to set up infinite number of timeout handlers.

setTimeout sets some function to be run in future but it ends running immediately, doesn't wait until function is ran. So while loop runs infinitely as there is nothing inside that changes health.

Other better solution is to use intervals - something like:

```
var game_interval;

function turn () {
  attack(0);
  eattack(0);
  if (health<=0 || ehealth<=0) {
    clearInterval(game_interval);
    dead();
  }
}

game_interval = setInterval(400,turn);
turn(); // first turn immediately
```